# CVS checkout without all of extra folders

Tags: jenkins, hudson, cvs, vcs-checkout

I want to checkout a specific folder from deep within a CVS module into my Hudson / Jenkins workspace. Stripping off the other options (such as pruning, branch, etc) the CVS command is ...

```
cvs checkout -d workspace module\a\b\c\d\e\f
```

This causes my folder to contain a child folder *'a'* and that contains *'b'* and that contains ... well you get the idea. All of them are empty until you get down to folder *'f'*.

What I'd really like is for *myfolder* to contain the contents of *f*. Does CVS support this functionality (without defining f as a module)?

And for bonus karma ... Can I get Jenkins to use this option with a .cvsrc or some other mechanism?

Comment: `$ CVS_RSH=ssh cvs -d anoncvs@anoncvs.jp.openbsd.org:/cvs/src/usr.bin/ssh checkout -P .` That is what I used to fetch just the content of `src/usr.bin/ssh` to the current directory. I'm not sure how your CSV repository is structured but maybe you could try `cvs checkout -d workspace/module/a/b/c/d/e/f .`. You can view the repository used in my example at https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/ssh/.

Answer (score 2):

I don't get the behaviour you describe. When I move to an empty directory and do

```
cvs checkout -d fox modules/a/quick/brown/fox
```

I just get a new directory called fox containing the contents of the directory I requested. (Note the forward slashes.)

However, if I do

```
cvs checkout modules/a/quick/brown/fox
```

then I get what you describe.

I'm using the latest FSF build of CVS on windows, http://ftp.gnu.org/non-gnu/cvs/binary/feature/x86-woe/cvs-1-12-13a.zip .

Comment: I've tried switching to that cvs.exe (I was using CVSNT) and changing to forward slashes. I still get the same behavior with the full a/b/c/de/f hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

There is a file called "modules", under your CVSROOT folder.
You can edit it, and a line like the following:

```
###shortcut name                            actual path########     
f                                         /a/b/c/d/e/f
```

Check this file back in. Once it sets in, you can just use

```
cvs checkout -d workspace f
```

Also, in Hudson, you can (in the Modules(s) ) box, just put f, and it should directly download only f, instead of the entire structure.
Once that is down, you could rename it using a shell/command.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have control over defining new modules. I'd need lots of them too (as lots of folders need mapping in this way). I was hoping to find an alternative solution, but this is still a good answer.

Comment: Hmm..unforunately, I'm not sure why Hudson is doing that. If you try the same command from the command line ( I just did ), you should get all the files & folders from "f" directly under the "workspace" directly...

Comment: It looks like there might be something different about your configuration, because vanilla CVS should not be behaving like that. Can you try this on another computer?

Answer (score 0):

More in General:

Go up 1 level above where you checked out

cvs co -r "TAG"